# DjangoCMS show menu on wrong language

Tags: django, django-cms

I have site https://www.mobydisc.de/. It have DE and EN versions. When i go to the site from browser, all content of site is on `DE`.

When i check site with https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch-details, content is on `DE`, but menu on `EN`.

How i can fix it?

**Settings :**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
1: [
    {
        'code': 'de',
        'name': gettext('Deutsch'),
        'fallbacks': ['en'],
        'public': True,
    },
    {
        'code': 'en',
        'name': gettext('English'),
        'fallbacks': ['de'],
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': True,
        'redirect_on_fallback':False,
    },
],
'default': {
    'fallbacks': ['de'],
    'redirect_on_fallback':True,
    'public': True,
    'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', 'Deutsch'),
    ('en', 'English'),
]
```

**Filter :**

```
@register.filter(name="get_menu_title_without_mega")
    def get_menu_title_without_mega(text):
        if megamenu(text):
            # print("mega remove")
            regexp  = re.compile("[ ]+mega[0-9]+$", re.MULTILINE)
            # print(text,regexp.sub("",text))
            return regexp.sub("",text)
        else:
            return text`
```

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtEmh.png)

Comment: Can you post the part of the template which renders the menu? (including any custom menu templates used by the menu tag)

Comment: @markwalker_ here https://gist.github.com/mki/1b722c54da5fcdcf970ae50fd966cae2

Comment: So what does `get_menu_title_without_mega` do? Is that feeding a string back without using `gettext`?

Comment: @markwalker_ add code of `get_menu_title_without_mega` at question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps me https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/218/

All i need to do is Ignore HTTP Accept-Language headers

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both 'de' and 'en' declared in LANGUAGES in your settings file. You are only showing 'de' in LANGUAGE_CODE and not showing us anything in LANGUAGES which I suspect might also only be declaring 'de'.

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

Comment: Yes, i have. Add them to my question.